# Create Classes from Text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit

I am trying to write a JavaScript loader for a project of mine for NW.js ([node-webkit](https://nwjs.io/)). I already sort of know my way around peg.js and estools (esprima/escodegen), so parsing the JavaScript modules into the various function and variable declarations is really no problem, the problem I have is with instantiating the different text-expressions and declarations into a separate context/object.

`eval()` does not seem to work for turning a declaration-string into a variable of my choice.

```
$.context.fn = eval("function anonymous(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; }");

//$.context.fn = undefined..
```

The only thing I can successfully convert from text to variable is functions:

```
$.context.fn = new Function('a','b','c','return a+b+c;');

//$.context.fn = function(a,b,c){ ... }
```

But there doesn't seem to be an analogous way of going about turning a string into a class for example:

```
$.context.cl = new Class(params,body) ???

//error
```

**Question:**

Is there maybe some sort of loader library I could use for this or are there maybe some tips to get the whole thing working with `eval()` after all?

Answer (score 2):

`eval` should work fine with any *expressions*:

```
$.context.fn = eval("(function anonymous(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; })");
$.context.cl = eval("(class { constructor() { … } … })");
```

However, `eval` always captures the local scope, which you'll probably not want. Either go for [global eval](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/), or use the trick with the function constructor to get the scope that you want. To instantiate a class, just create a function that returns said class (or any other language construct):

```
$.context.fn = (new Function("function named(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; }\nreturn named;"))();
$.context.cl = (new Function("class Example { constructor() { … } … }\nreturn Example;"))();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that

```
function anonymous(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; }
```

is a functions declaration, not a function expression. Function declaration do not return anything: they define a new function with the name provided. In this case the name is `anonymous`.

You want to use a function expression instead. [See this MDN section for an explanation of the differences.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Function_constructor_vs._function_declaration_vs._function_expression) You can make a function expression by wrapping the function in parentheses:

```
$.context.fn = eval("(function anonymous(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; })");
```

[Class declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class) and [class expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/class) work the same way:

```
$.context.cls = eval("(class MyArray extends Array {})")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create functions with eval:

1)

```
eval("function anonymous(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; }");
console.log(anonymous(1,2,3));
```

2)

```
eval('var fn = function(a,b,c) { return a+b+c;};');
console.log(fn(1,2,3));
```

3)

```
eval("function anonymous(a,b,c){ return a+b+c; }");
var fn = anonymous;
console.log(fn(1,2,3));
```